# Notification of undeletion

Tags: feature-request, notifications, deleted-answers, undelete

A post of mine that I deleted later got undeleted by three other users, but I only became aware of the undeletion a couple of months afterwards when the post received an upvote. Would there be a way to provide immediate notification to the user when a post of theirs gets undeleted, similar to the notification the user receives when a post of theirs gets edited?

Here is some [related discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32688/3736).

Comment: I would advocate extending this request to deletions as well as undeletions, to questions as well as answers, and perhaps even to question closures and migrations.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin please no. All I expect is every closure and delete being discussed on Meta.

Comment: What had you done if you was notified of the undeletion? Delete it again?

Comment: @rene can also reconsider, especially if those who undeleted add a comment explaining why they did it.

Comment: @rene In this case I would probably have let the undeletion stand since the situation which originally caused me to delete had changed somewhat. In another situation I might have chosen to redelete. In general I would prefer knowing when any change has been made by another user to something I wrote.

Comment: I have the unpopular opinion that once you posted something it is no longer only to you to decide if a post stays up or gets deleted. Any features that brings an OP closely in that moderation loop needs scrutiny to prevent that moderation of content gets harder and/or blocked.

Comment: I completely agree with your point @rene. Content is licensed under CC-BY-SA for a reason. OP has no right to remove it from the network when others disagree

Comment: @rene I don't think keeping the system less transparent so that creators of the original content are less likely to interfere with moderation is good policy. The way things stand, there's nothing to prevent the author from redeleting later should they eventually become aware of the undeletion. And the undeleters are likely to be none the wiser. At least with notification there's the possibility of engagement. Also, the author is likely to know their own post better than anybody else, and to be in better position to point out subtle issues or backstory that might have escaped others' notice.